# How to make reverse transition after :hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

From my understanding of CSS3 transitions you have to specify the transition only in the base element and not in the `:hover` element, e.g. as described in the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions). This should lead to a transition when the new properties from `:hover` are applied and reverse the transition as soon as you don't hover anymore. (Fiddle below code)

```
#test{
    position:absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #A8A8A8;

    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#test:hover{
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}
```

But this leads to fading-in only. When you stop hovering the border is instantly removed.
http://jsfiddle.net/hcsamkjf/1/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to specify the "initial state", otherwise the browser doesn't know what to animate. It can *sometimes* guess, which would be why you see it half-working (but it doesn't transition at all for me).

Add `border-bottom:10px solid transparent` or `border-bottom:0 solid transparent` to your `#test` styles, depending on the exact effect you want.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation with the guessing. I hate behaviour like this from software, an error message would be way more helpful so you can just make it properly.

Comment: But it's not an error. The browser did exactly what you told it to do. You failed to actually tell it what to do.

Comment: Might be... I'm from a Java world where something like this would most likely violate some contract and won't let you compile... Anyway, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that as you are not specifying a [`border-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) in the initial state, when you "unhover", the animation changes from solid to the [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) : `none`. Border-style [isn't animatable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) so the change is sudden.

You need to specify the same `border-style` in the initial state (*note: specify a 0 `border-width` too to remove default border width*) so the animation only affects border-width and stays smooth in both directions.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/hcsamkjf/2/)**

*CSS :*

```
#test{
    position:absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #A8A8A8;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:0px;

    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#test:hover{
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}
```